# 10 minutes wind speed data to 1 second wind speed data

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-chain

I have a wind speed data series .txt file (1 year long), in which in each register I have the following info:

date; hour; 10 minute wind speed average; 10 minute max value; 10 minute sigma

An example of the data would be like this:

050206 0130 8.05 10.28 0.84

050206 0150 7.29 11.06 1.13 ....

For each 10 minutes, the available information is the wind speed average, the maximum value in such 10 minutes and the standard deviation in such 10 minutes. Such statistics for each 10 minutes are calculated with 1 s sampling data (600 values for each 10 minutes).

It can be assumed that the 1 s sampled values are Normally distributed. The problem is that such 1 s sampled values are not available and I need them for my study.

So, the questions are:

-Is there a mathematical/statistical solid well known method to generate the 1 s values for each 10 minute register assuming that they are Normally distributed??

-Is there a mathematical/statistical solid well known method to link each 1 s values with coherence??

I would like to implement a Python script in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following problem in reverse. I had data for 600 people and I recorded the mean and SD of their height and I noted also that height is normally distributed. But I threw away the 600 individual height measurements. Can you tell me the heights of the 600 people?

You can not solve this problem. You could simulate from a distribution with those properties, but you cannot solve this problem. Data once discarded cannot be recovered.

Your problem is not identical in form, as you have a time series. But how could that help? If you were willing to make some physically dubious assumptions about wind speed changing according to some scheme you could perhaps make better guesses than just simulating, but you are asking for white magic where no magic exists.

You used the tags "monte carlo" and "markov chain", but it is not clear to me why.

Comment: What I really want is to simulate/generate the 1-sec data, nothing about solving. Sorry if I expressed myself uncorrectly.

Comment: What do you want the simulated values for? They will just be multiple blocks with differing means and standard deviations. Computationally that would just be a matter of calling up some routine for randomly sampling from a normal or Gaussian. Somebody should have done that within Python, but in any case how to do in any software it is off-topic here unless you have a novel statistical question about generating random normal deviates.